# how can I get ubuntu to boot with a specific setting

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I was wondering how could I get ubuntu to keep this setting
xrandr --output LVDS1 --off

the issue is that every time I boot the computer i have to enter it again

thanks :D

I apologize for being such a newb,
I just started using linux

Comment: PS: remember there is an Unbuntu SE.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is adding it to `/etc/rc.local` before `exit 0`, then it will run on every boot. From the header of `/etc/rc.local`,

> This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
>   Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
>   value on error.